# EJB (@Singleton) creates a lot of Threads

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

I have a question regarding to a strange behavior of my Java EE application.
I had created a @Singleton EJB to schedule a process.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class BackgroundEmailLoader {

    @PostConstruct
     public void init (){
        DO SOMETHING
      }

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*/1", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void loadNewEmailsJob() {

        // TO SOMETHING


    }
}
```

Now every minute when the job starts, a new Thread (Default-EJB) is created and all other Threads of this task are still running. After some minutes there are a lot of Threads created. Is this a normal behavior? Could this cause a memory problem?

Technology Stack: Wildfly 8, Java EE 7

Comment: In a singleton, there should normally not be multiple threads active in one method. If the execution takes longer than 1 minute, the new attempts would block. Also, why do you use an early Alpha version of JBoss/WildFly?

Comment: Question seems to be solved. When the maximum count of 10 threads is reached, the server stops to create new threads, i don't know why but so far the applcation doesen't make indication to get memory problems.